# How to find a list of files in a specific directory without dirent.h or boost

Tags: c++, file

I need to make this header that can find file names from a directory for a school project though it is important to mention that my teacher is very strict and i'm not allowed to use libraries that are already made (dirent.h, boost etc). To put it simply, i have to make it from scratch.

The only 2 functions i'm actually allowed to use are

```
// They more test accesibility rather than actual existance but it is enough

// LPCSTR = constant long pointer to string
// similar to:  char* pathToFile 

bool DoesFileExist(LPCSTR pathToFile)  
{
    std::ifstream file(pathToFile);
    return file.good();
}

bool DoesDirExist(LPCSTR pathToDir)
{
     DWORD dwAttrib = GetFileAttributes(pathToDir);
     return (dwAttrib != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES && (dwAttrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY));
}
```

I tought a recursive function will work best if i just needed to print the names. This is how the code should act like.

```
void PrintSubfiles(LPCSTR CurrentDirectory)
{
    CHAR pathToSomething[MAX_PATH];
    // this is where the string takes the path of either a file or a directory
    // I imagined the principle of the GetNextPath() function similar to strtok()
    GetNextPath(CurrentDirectory,pathToSomething); 

    while (pathToSomething != NULL)
    {
        if (DoesDirExist(pathToSomething))
        {
             // print the name of this directory and enter it
             std::cout<<"IN DIRECTORY: "<<pathToSomething<<std::endl;
             PrintSubFiles(pathToSomething);   
        }

        if (DoesFileExist(pathToSomething))
        {
             // print the file name
             std::cout<<"FILE: "<<pathToSomething<<std::endl;
        }

        GetNextPath(NULL,pathToSomething);
    }
}
```

I actually have no idea how to implement the `GetNextPath()` function. It doesen't need to be super fast or memory efficient. I just need to get the data to that `pathToSomething` string. Any idea how to do it without those libraries ?

EDIT: This header is specifically for windows. No need for portable solutions.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You're allowed to use `GetFileAttributes`, but not anything from `dirent.h`? Are you allowed to use `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile`? Each of these is equally from "libraries that are already made." You might want to find a different teacher.

Comment: I don't understand these "requirements".  Even if you used `boost`, you still have to learn how to use it -- the program isn't going to magically write itself.  Also, if you're using the Windows API, why the restriction on what 2 or 3 functions to use?  Has the C++ teaching world gone wild?

Comment: I asked myself that teach gone wild question too but i simply can't understand what she wants. She simply said "Use THESE FUNCTIONS only" though i doubt it is possible with this two only after what i have read on MSDN.

Comment: If you are only allowed to use those two functions you cannot complete this assignment.

Comment: Are you using C++ 17? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem